# Text field data not passing properly in form POST method

Tags: php, html, forms

I am working on a digital employment application for my company using HTML and processing with PHP.

The form is defined by:`<form method="post" action="./php/post.php" name="empapp">` and the text field is defined by: `<input size="13" name="canyoufeelityeah">`

My PHP page contains the following lines:
`print_r( $_POST);
        print_r( $_POST["canyoufeelityeah"]);

```
    if  (($_POST["canyoufeelityeah"] = ' ') or ($_POST["initials2"] = ' ') or ($_POST["initials3"] = ' ') or ($_POST["initials4"] = ' ') or ($_POST["signature"] = ' '))  
    {
        echo $_POST["canyoufeelityeah"]."|".$_POST["initials2"]."|".$_POST["initials3"]."|".$_POST["initials4"]."|".$_POST["signature"]."|";
        echo "You must initial each of the 4 blocks and sign your name at the bottom. <br />You will be redirected to your application in 15 seconds...";
       // echo "<script>setTimeout(\"window.history.back()\", 1500)</script>";
    }`
```

The printing of all the $_POST variables shows the variable "canyoufeelityeah" with the value, but this section of code always pulls a blank.

Can anyone help out with this?   I have approximately 30 other variables that are being passed, but this one is the only one giving me any problems, and I am not sure why.

Thanks!

Comment: it should be `==`(double equal) at if condition not `=`(single equal)

Comment: Thanks guys.  I will try that and get back to you.

Comment: I tried changing it to the comparison operator (==) and now the code isn't catching the missing data from the web page like it should.  It was catching it before, except that it couldn't find the one field (canyoufeelityeah).

Comment: you should use `==`on all `=` at if condition

Comment: updated code snippet that doesn't work: `if  (($_POST["canyoufeelityeah"] == ' ') or ($_POST["initials2"] == ' ') or ($_POST["initials3"] == ' ') or ($_POST["initials4"] == ' ') or ($_POST["signature"] == ' '))  
       `

Comment: what do you mean not work what actually you want?

Comment: The code is supposed to catch if there is no data in those 5 text fields.  I tested by omitting data in those fields and the code does not catch the error here.  before I put the == (double equal) in, the code was working properly for 4 of the 5 fields.  "canyoufeelityeah"  was not recognizing that there was data in it when it was being called in the PHP code

Comment: see my solution.I think you wanted that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
if  (empty($_POST["canyoufeelityeah"]) or empty($_POST["initials2"]) or empty($_POST["initials3"]) or empty($_POST["initials4"]) or empty($_POST["signature"]))
    {
        echo $_POST["canyoufeelityeah"]."|".$_POST["initials2"]."|".$_POST["initials3"]."|".$_POST["initials4"]."|".$_POST["signature"]."|";
        echo "You must initial each of the 4 blocks and sign your name at the bottom. <br />You will be redirected to your application in 15 seconds...";
        // echo "<script>setTimeout(\"window.history.back()\", 1500)</script>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `assignment` and not `comparison` in your `if` statements.

You wrote: 
`($_POST["canyoufeelityeah"] = ' ')`

It should be:
`($_POST["canyoufeelityeah"] == ' ')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think you forgot the '=='

```
if  (($_POST["canyoufeelityeah"] == ' ') or ($_POST["initials2"] == ' ') or ($_POST["initials3"] == ' ') or ($_POST["initials4"] == ' ') or ($_POST["signature"] == ' '))  
    {
        echo $_POST["canyoufeelityeah"]."|".$_POST["initials2"]."|".$_POST["initials3"]."|".$_POST["initials4"]."|".$_POST["signature"]."|";
        echo "You must initial each of the 4 blocks and sign your name at the bottom. <br />You will be redirected to your application in 15 seconds...";
       // echo "<script>setTimeout(\"window.history.back()\", 1500)</script>";
    }`
```